# simple Nginx proxy_pass gives back 502

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location, proxypass

Im trying to do a very basic task of redirecting between two servers based on "http referer".

I have tried a basic If, but I know IF IS EVIL in nginx and didnt manage to make it work, so came up with this solution, of directing based on valid_referer. but Im keep getting 502.

```
    server {
    
    location /application1 {
                        valid_referers server_names
                             .click2dad.net*;
                if ($invalid_referer){
    set $1 '';
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/$1;
    
                }
    
    }
}
```

server 2:

```
server {
        listen 8080;
        root /home/ubuntu/data/server2;

}
```

btw I used set $1 = "" , since I kept getting an error if proxy_pass cannot have uri under if statment

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have something running on `http://localhost:8080/` .

Do something to check whether port 8080 is used by any process, like

`netstat -tulpn | grep 8080`
on your terminal.